# Multiplicity issue while mapping a table in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I currently have a class:

```
[Table("TitleCategoryMovie", Schema = "dbo")]
public class TitleCategoryMovie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDatetime { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDatetime { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual Title Title { get; set; }
}
```

There is a table called `Title`. And every `TitleCategoryMovie` has a corresponding `Title`, although not every `Title` has a `TitleCategoryMovie`. The column `Id` for Title is also the same for TitleCategoryMovie. But when I add both entity classes to my DbContext, it gives me an error:

`Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'TitleCategoryMovieStandalone_Title_Source' in relationship 'TitleCategoryMovieStandalone_Title'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be �1�.`

I've already defined my column `Id` in `TitleCategoryMovie` as a primary key and a foreign key to `Title`, so I don't know why it's giving me this error. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mapping two entities to one table. Apparently this isn't allowed in Entity Framework, so that was why I was getting that error.

Comment: It must have been something else because it is perfectly possible to map one table to two entities. But when I asked you, said you were mapping two tables to two entities?

Comment: I also had another entity class that was mapped to TitleCategoryMovie, but I didn't know that was relevant to my question, so I didn't include it.

Answer (score 0):

You should also add a `TitleId` field and use that one as the parameter in the `[ForeignKey]` attribute:

```
[Table("TitleCategoryMovie", Schema = "dbo")]
public class TitleCategoryMovie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDatetime { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDatetime { get; set; }
    public int TitleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TitleId")]
    public virtual Title Title { get; set; }
}
```

#### Update after comments

I believe something like this should work:

```
[Table("TitleCategoryMovie", Schema = "dbo")]
public class TitleCategoryMovie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDatetime { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDatetime { get; set; }

    public virtual Title Title { get; set; }
}

[Table("Title", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Title
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("TitleCategoryMovie")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Something { get; set; }

    public virtual TitleCategoryMovie TitleCategoryMovie { get; set; }
}
```

You should put the `[ForeignKey]` attribute in the class that you consider to be the child of the relationship.

Comment: Why do I need to add a separate column for TitleId? Why can't I just use Id as both a primary and foreign key?

Comment: Ooooh, you are storing both the data from the TitleCategoryMovie class and the Title class in one table?

Comment: No. I have two tables TitleCategoryMovie and Title. But both have Id columns, except the Id column for TitleCategoryMovie is also a foreign key to Title's Id column.

Comment: So those tables have a one-to-one mapping?

Comment: 0..1 to 1. If the Title is type TitleCategoryMovie, then it will have a corresponding row in table TitleCategoryMovie. Otherwise it will have a different category and a row in another table.

Comment: TitleCategoryMovie is a child of Title. There is no TitleCategoryMovie entry without a Title entry, but a Title entry can exist without a TitleCategoryMovie entry.